# Host name and IP address change while transfer an Amazon EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have EC2 Ubuntu instance that runs MQTT service. I'm planning to transfer this instance to my client account. Will IP adders and hostname of this instance change during this procedure? Will MQTT clients find new service by the same address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to "transfer" an EC2 instance to a different AWS account. You would have to take a snapshot of the server, copy the snapshot, and then create an entirely new server from the snapshot.

So yes, the hostname and IP address are definitely going to change.